# Monitoring intermittent MobileFirst application crashes

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

How do I obtain more information, in addition to server logs and trace, on my application that crashes from time to time?

Answer (score 0):

Application crashes can be tracked via the Analytics Console. By using Analytics SDK, the user setcontext api's to set the user in the application. That will ensure the application user data
and the crash captured (when the app starts next time to connect to the Mobilefirst server). This way one can capture the crash logs and analytics from the deviceId and user perspective.

More details: 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_op_analytics_data_capture.html#c_op_analytics_data_capture__manually_captured_data (see the [crash report] section)